# GET URL parameter in PHP %24 ($) with a number after it won't echo correctly %241%2C995.00

Tags: php, url, get

I'm using $_GET to show some parameters from my URL on page. Everything works fine but one parameter - totalprice. For example in this URL:

https://justpaintmyhouse.com/your-are-all-set/?startdate=04/30/2014&fname=First+Name&email=something%40gmail.com&totalprice=%241%2C995.00&projectzip=999999&projectstate=Georgia&projectcity=CIty&projectst=123+Street+Rd

On the page I use:
    echo $_GET['totalprice']

And it should be $1,995.00 but all I get is ,995.00

Is there another way to get the parameter it will recognize there is a $ sign and a number after it?

Comment: what is your server? in my mac, it goes well.

Comment: It works fine here as well...

Comment: So you both get "a guaranteed fixed price of $1,995.00" show on the page? I tested it on all browsers (win 8) and my Iphone (chrome) and all I get is "guaranteed fixed price of ,995.00"

Comment: working here too.(chrome Ubuntu)

Answer (score 2):

It seem to be an issue with the WP plugin I used to put PHP inside the page (Insert PHP). I switched to another one - (URL Params) and it seem to work fine. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
rawurldecode($_GET['totalprice']);
```

Comment: Thanks but it did not solve the issue - as I posted just now it was probably a plugin issue.